# How to make Kenny, Ben, Christa and Omid help me find Clementine?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I know I should've been careful choosing words when talking to Kenny but the dude really pisses me off.

And so, I got mad and I told him mean words which made him even mad ( though he's always a pain in the .. )

I just want to know if how can I convince him to come with me and help me find Clementine.

*in the meantime, I only got Ben, Christa and Omid. Obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This point in the game is the culmination of the relationship between Lee and the other characters, so there's a lot of potential ways it could be altered.  The [Walking Dead Wikia lists the following for all the characters involved:](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Around_Every_Corner)

> The player can choose to go alone on the search for her or ask for help.
>
> - Christa and Omid will offer to help if the player shows the group Lee's bite (or if the player chose to leave an armed Clementine at the house during the trip to Crawford.)
> - Kenny will help if the player sides with him in every argument throughout the game and sticks with him through major decisions (alternatively, the player can choose the response to his denial for help, "Clementine is my family." If the player treated Duck and Katjaa in a good fashion before their deaths, Kenny will agree to come along.)
> - Ben (if saved) will willingly help if asked to, but will tag along of his own volition if the player had shown him support throughout the past 2 episodes or mention about Clementine supporting him, he will come along.

So it seems that specifically for Kenny, you've got a couple options:

- If you supported him throughout the game, he'll volunteer.
- If you helped Duck and Katjaa through the game, and tell Lee that Clementine is your family, he'll join you.

In my case, I fed and stood up for Duck whenever I could, and I didn't make Kenny pull the trigger when the time came.  I was kind and supportive towards Katjaa as well.  Kenny didn't immediately want to help me, as I didn't support him in the meat locker and on a few other occasions.  However, appealing to his sense of family caused him to come with me.

Answer (score 0):

**Kenny** - Kenny will come with you if you agree with him in the drugstore and help him in the meat locker. If you only do one of those things or neither Of them, then when he denies helping you tell him that clementine is your family and he will come with you

**Christa and Omid** - Christa and Omid will come with you if you reveal the bite to the group. If you choose to hide the bite, then you have to leave clementine at the house when you go to Crawford and trust her with a gun.

**Ben** - If you choose to pull up Ben at the bell tower, Ben will come with you if he likes you or if you mention that clementine supported him.

Answer (score -2):

When the first time I played this game, I didn't sided with Kenny in the meat locker but still in the episode around every corner, I didn't even had to convince him to come with me, he was ready to go with me (I killed Ben in that episode tho). But when I played this game for the second time, i did the same things this time too the only difference was that this time I didn't involved myself in much conversations with him or his family (as I knew the story this time and was eager to complete is ASAP) and I saved Ben this time too. But this time I had to convince him to come with me. So in my opinion, the meat locker scene doesn't makes much difference, you just have to talk to him and his family a lot and show that you care for them.